# Access violation reading location with openCL with high n values

Tags: c, opencl, opencl-c

I have to program the Floyd algorithm using OpenCL, it works fine but only with n<268. when n>=268 i have an "Access violation reading location" when calling clEnqueueWriteBuffer (the buffer_distances one, in the loop).

Here is my code:

graphe is an adjacency matrix, and distances is the distances matrix

```
    int n;
    printf("enter n value: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n");
    int n2 = n * n;
    int matSize = n2 * sizeof(int*);
    int* graphe = malloc(sizeof(int) * n2);
    int* distances = malloc(sizeof(int) * n2);
    //mat[i,j] => mat[i*n + j]
    if (graphe == NULL)
        printf("malloc failed\n");
    init_graphe(graphe, n);
    copy(graphe, distances, n);
```

initialization of opencl variables:

```
    char* programSource = load_kernel("kernel.cl");

    cl_int status;
    // STEP 1: Discover and initialize the platforms

    cl_uint numPlatforms = 0;

    cl_platform_id* platforms = NULL;

    status = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
    printf("Number of platforms = %d\n", numPlatforms);

    platforms = (cl_platform_id*)malloc(numPlatforms * sizeof(cl_platform_id));

    status = clGetPlatformIDs(numPlatforms, platforms, NULL);

    char Name[1000];
    clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[0], CL_PLATFORM_NAME, sizeof(Name), Name, NULL);
    printf("Name of platform : %s\n", Name);
    fflush(stdout);

    // STEP 2: Discover and initialize the devices

    cl_uint numDevices = 0;
    cl_device_id* devices = NULL;

    status = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 0, NULL, &numDevices);


    printf("Number of devices = %d\n", (int)numDevices);

    devices = (cl_device_id*)malloc(numDevices * sizeof(cl_device_id));

    status = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, numDevices, devices, NULL);


    for (int i = 0; i < numDevices; i++) {
        clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_NAME, sizeof(Name), Name, NULL);
        printf("Name of device %d: %s\n\n", i, Name);
    }

    // STEP 3: Create a context
    fflush(stdout);

    cl_context context = NULL;

    context = clCreateContext(NULL, numDevices, devices, NULL, NULL, &status);

    // STEP 4: Create a command queue
    fflush(stdout);
    cl_command_queue cmdQueue;

    cmdQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, devices[0], 0, &status);

    // STEP 5: Create device buffers
    fflush(stdout);

    cl_mem buffer_graphe;
    cl_mem buffer_n;
    cl_mem buffer_distances;
    cl_mem buffer_k;

    buffer_graphe = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, matSize, NULL, &status);
    buffer_n = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int), NULL, &status);
    buffer_distances = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, matSize, NULL, &status);
    buffer_k = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int), NULL, &status);
    fflush(stdout);

    // STEP 6: Create and compile the program
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**)&programSource, NULL, &status);
    printf("Compilation\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    status = clBuildProgram(program, numDevices, devices, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // STEP 8: Create the kernel
    cl_kernel kernel = NULL;
    fflush(stdout);
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "floyd", &status);

    size_t globalWorkSize[2] = { n, n };
    size_t localWorkSize[3] = { 20,20 };
```

Execution of the kernel:

```
    clock_t start = clock();
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cmdQueue, buffer_graphe, CL_TRUE, 0, matSize, graphe, 0, NULL, NULL);
        status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cmdQueue, buffer_n, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int), &n, 0, NULL, NULL);
        status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cmdQueue, buffer_distances, CL_TRUE, 0, matSize, distances, 0, NULL, NULL);
        status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cmdQueue, buffer_k, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int), &k, 0, NULL, NULL);

        status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&buffer_graphe);
        status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&buffer_n);
        status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&buffer_distances);
        status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&buffer_k);

        status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdQueue, kernel, 2, NULL, globalWorkSize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
        clFinish(cmdQueue);  

        status = clEnqueueReadBuffer(cmdQueue, buffer_distances, CL_TRUE, 0, matSize, distances, 0, NULL, NULL);
        clFinish(cmdQueue);
    }
```

and the kernel:

```
void kernel floyd(global int* graphe, global int* n, global int* distances, global int* k)
{
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    int j = get_global_id(1);

    int ij = i * (*n) + j;
    int ik = i * (*n) + (*k);
    int kj = (*k) * (*n) + j;

    if (distances[ik] + distances[kj] < distances[ij]) {
        distances[ij] = distances[ik] + distances[kj];
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all [in C you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/). Secondly, I don't see any kind of error checking, does you real code have it (for example to check `malloc` doesn't fail)?

Comment: And please try to create a [mre] to show us. What is `matSize`? How are `graphe` and `buffer_graphe` related (I assume they should be)?

Comment: Ok, i wrote more if my code. i removed the cast before malloc and checked if they worked. they did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
int matSize = n2 * sizeof(int*);
…
int* distances = malloc(sizeof(int) * n2);
…
status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cmdQueue, buffer_distances, CL_TRUE, 0, matSize, distances, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

- Say n2 is 100.
- `matSize` will be 800 on a 64-bit system. (`sizeof(int*)` = 8)
- You allocate 400 bytes of memory for your `distances` array. (`sizeof(int)` = 4, typically)
- You then copy 800 bytes (`matSize`) from `distances` into your OpenCL buffer. This overflows the end of the array. Whoops.

The bug is of course the use of `sizeof(int*)`: you've got an array of `int`s, not an array of pointers, so this should be `sizeof(int)`, which is what you're correctly doing in the `malloc` call. (I can't quite fathom why you're not using `matSize` there.) Although what you should probably be using is `CLint`, or one of the explicitly-sized types (`int32_t` in this case), because types in OpenCL kernels have very specific definitions which may or may not match those in host C code.

**Additional Notes:**

- **I'm not 100% convinced your data dependencies are safe here.** No work-item should be *reading* an array entry that another is *writing* in the same kernel enqueueing batch. It seems to me that `ij` (written) for one of the work-items will be equal to `ik` (read) for the others in the row? Similar deal with `ij` and `kj`.
- There's no need to read and re-write the `distances` buffer between iterations, if you're not modifying it on the host. Neither does `graphe` need re-writing every time if it's not changing.
- You can pass scalar arguments such as `k` and `n` without a buffer. `status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(n), &n);` works fine if you change your kernel signature's argument to `int n`. (no dereference needed in the kernel then.)
- A local work size of 20x20 is likely not optimal. If you're not using local memory or barriers, don't bother setting a local size at al.
- You *should* be able to remove the `clFinish` calls, and you can change the buffer writes to be non-blocking once you've moved them outside the loop. This might give you an additional small speedup.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is around twice faster than mine !

Comment: @alex I've added some more notes. Performance aside, I'm not sure your algorithm implementation is correct, there may be data races.

Answer (score -1):

I think i found the solution, i replaced malloc by calloc, and now it works.

Comment: `calloc` is usually preferable to `malloc`, but the use of `malloc` in your code is not itself an error (aside perhaps from potential numerical overflows); the incorrect computation of `matSize` and its subsequent use for indexing the smaller array is.